# Regex for parsing function command line arguments

Tags: c, regex

How i can parse the following function command line:
The separtor is (\s-\w\s) like -c or -d or -n

```
C:/my app/bin/Reader.dll -n Proc_20ms -c C:/Users/Braun/Desktop/test.csv -t Continue the simulation from the first line of the csv-file -j none -V errors and warnings (default) -d ,
```

to:

```
Match1:  C:/my app/bin/Reader.dll
Match2: -n
Match3: Proc_20ms
Match4: -c
Match5: C:/Users/Braun/Desktop/test.csv
Match6: -t
Match7: Continue the simulation from the first line of the csv-file 
Match8: -j
Match9: none
Match10: -V
Match11: errors and warnings (default)
Match12: -d
Match13: ,
```

Thanks.

Comment: If you just want to parse command line arguments, you should check argparse library

Comment: Use [getopt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getopt). There's no point in reinventing this wheel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put `-\w` inside a capturing group and then use this regex in  `re.split` function. capturing group is necessary, so that it would keep the delimiter (ie, only the chars present inside the capturing group).

```
>>> s = 'C:/my app/bin/Reader.dll -n Proc_20ms -c C:/Users/Braun/Desktop/test.csv -t Continue the simulation from the first line of the csv-file -j none -V errors and warnings (default) -d ,'
>>> for i in re.split(r'\s(-\w)\s', s):
        print(i)


C:/my app/bin/Reader.dll
-n
Proc_20ms
-c
C:/Users/Braun/Desktop/test.csv
-t
Continue the simulation from the first line of the csv-file
-j
none
-V
errors and warnings (default)
-d
,
```

Comment: Thanks for you fast answer. but i use qt with c++,therefore i need a regexp.

Comment: but i saw a python tag on your question.

Comment: that was my fault sorry. was i need you can test them under: https://regex101.com/r/pR8oF5/1 please change the text to : C:/my app/bin/Reader.dll -n Proc_20ms -c C:/Users/Braun/Desktop/test.csv -t Continue the simulation from the first line of the csv-file -j none -V  errors and warnings (default) -d ,

Comment: with regexp (\s(-\w)\s")|(\S+) I miss the blank, then the argument is erroneous with blank,

Comment: have it tested? is still incorrect. Please test:  C:/my app/bin/Reader.dll -n Proc_20ms -c C:/Users/Braun/Desktop/test.csv -t Continue the simulation from the first line of the csv-file -j none -V errors and warnings (default) -d ,

Comment: Please see https://regex101.com/r/pR8oF5/8   match9 till match 23 is not correct.